# stsadm migrateuser: The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: administration, stsadm, user-profile, security, active-directory

I'm running:

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin "domain1\user" -newlogin "domain2\user" -ignoreidhistory
```

and getting the error "The user does not exist or is not unique".

The users exist in both domains in AD. The oldlogin has a user profile and also has membership to SharePoint Groups.

I've been on Google and I've read [Todd Klindt's](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=75) awesome post but still no dice! Any suggestions.

I basically have created a new domain (domain2), created a new user for an individual in that domain and want to run migrateuser on existing domain (domain1) account so the individual retains all the permissions etc.

I've tried using the API too with PowerShell and get the same error with this approach too!

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration") | out-null
$spFarm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPfarm]::Local;
$spFarm.MigrateUserAccount($oldusername, $newusername, $true);
```

Comment: I've also followed Todd's steps with the database and in the UserInfo table only "domain1\user" exists not "domain2\user".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the new domain did not have a trust with the domain that the SharePoint Farm was a member of and so the migrateuser command was failing to resolve the new user.

Would have been nice for the migrateuser command to give some more defensive helpful error messages! Clearly too much to ask for...maybe in SP2010 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

i've had similar problems before and it's been because the details of the account, in the two ADs, has differed slightly.

make sure the details of the two user accounts are identical (eg. all information, such as title, manager, phone etc).

If i remember correctly, then there's a script in the source code (a .bat file i believe) of this CodeProject entry:

- [SPUpdateUserInfoList](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPUpdateUserInfoList.aspx)

the code is not all relevant to you, but the .bat file might help.

If not, then let me know and we'll keep working on it :)

Comment: there was quite a few bat files in there mate, nothing that looked relevant to migrateuser?

Comment: when you say "identical"? the username's are obviously different. I thought this allowed you to transfer to a new user, e.g. to give all the permisssions and ownership "domain1\user" had to "domain2\user" had without too much checking. is there anywhere that documents what it does in background. Todd's one is what I thought it did.

Comment: the .bat file you're looking for is the "Install AD Updator.bat".

when i say "identical" i mean that the title and other things has to be the same...

if you read over that article then the problems they're referring to are very much the same - part of that solution also resolved the people picker issue that you're mentioning you have.